# sklearn feature.Extraction 'DictVectorizer' object has no attribute 'feature_names_'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, transform

Whenever I call `transform` it keeps giving me the following error :

```
AttributeError:'DictVectorizer' object has no attribute 'feature_names_'
```

This is the function call:

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
x_test = vec.transform(X_features)
```

My python version is 2.7, `Scipy 0.16.0`, `numpy 1.9.2+mkl`, `scikit-learn 0.16.1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means, that the `DictVectorizer` was not fitted prior to transforming `X_features` into it's corresponding matrix format.

You need to call `vec.fit(X_features)` followed by `vec.transform(X_features)`, or more succintly `X_test = vec.fit_transform(X_features)`. `DictVectorizer` needs to know the keys of all the passed dictionaries, so that the transformation of unseen data consistently yields the same number of columns and column order.